# Integral of $Re(z)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

i was ask to prove that

$$\int_{-1}^{1} Re(z) dz$$ is not well defined.

My attemp:

I want to prove that there is two countor $C_1$ and $C_2$ that connect -1 and 1 such that
$$\int_{C_1} Re(z) dz \not =\int_{C_1} Re(z) dz$$

Let $C_1$: $[-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined as follow  $t \mapsto t$

Adn $C_2$: $[0,\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined as follow $t \mapsto e^{it}$

So
$$\int_{C_1} Re(z) dz= \int_{-1}^{1} t dt=0$$

and
$$\int_{C_2} Re(z) dz= \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{t}\cdot ie^{it}= i \int_{0}^{\pi}e^{t(1+i)}= \dfrac{e^o}{1+i}-\dfrac{e^{\pi(1+i}}{1+i}\not =0$$

Is my answer ok?

Comment: It is not $\text{Re}\int_{-1}^1 zdz$?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for which the integral is that the real part of $z$ is nowhere analytical.

However, I am afraid that you have reached a correct conclusion for a wrong reason.
$$
\int_{C_2} \operatorname{Re} {(z)} \,\mathrm{d}z
= \int_{0}^{2\pi/2} \operatorname{Re} {(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t})}\, \mathrm{i} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t} \,\mathrm{d}t
= \int_{0}^{2\pi/2} (-\sin t \cos t + \mathrm{i} \cos^2 t) \,\mathrm{d}t
= \frac{2\pi \mathrm{i}}{4}.
$$

Comment: +1 but why write $2\pi/2$ and $\frac{2\pi \mathrm{i}}4$ instead of  $\pi$ and $\frac{\pi \mathrm{i}}2?$

Comment: @AnneBauval I think that that is because I favor $2\pi$ over its half. I could have used $\tau$ instead, but that piece of notation is not widely used. (I do use $\tau$ in my notes, which are private, however.)